# Rails GeoLiteCity GeoIP Doesn't Work In Local Development Environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, geoip

I have the GeoIP.dat (country) and GeoLiteCity.dat (city) data from MaxMind. The country data works fine in my local Rails development but when I try to find the city data it returns null.

However when I deploy to Heroku, the city data does return the correct values. Any idea why the country data works in local development while the city data doesn't?

Works in Heroku, not in local:

```
geoip = GeoIP.new('geoip/GeoLiteCity.dat').city(request.remote_ip)
```

Works in both:

```
geoip = GeoIP.new('geoip/GeoIP.dat').country(request.remote_ip)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that for some reason Maxmind entered in private IP networks into the country database, but [rightly so] didn't for the city database.

You should code things so that if you don't get a result you set it to something (if you rely on it elsewhere).  It happens (especially in development).  In my project I set it to the city for the company's head quarters.

Comment: Yea, I added in a if statement to check to see if it was there and if so then get the geoip data, otherwise skip it. But I still have a bunch of "unnecessary" commits while trying to get everything to work since I have to test in heroku :)

Comment: @TomHammond You can't test locally at all?